# Uploading sudoers.d file through ansible gives syntax error but opening and saving in vi fixes it

Tags: linux, sudo, ansible, sudoedit, template

Alright, I know the question title sucks, but it's the same with the situation itself.

What I am trying to do is this:

1. Create a file with sudoers configuration locally
2. Use Ansible to ubload that file with the template module
3. Use the validate feature of the template module to make sure the configuration works

So far, so good. Now comes the weird part: The validation (`validate: 'visudo -cf %s'`) of that file throws an error. When I comment out the validation line the files gets uploaded, but a manual validation (`visudo -cf /etc/sudoers.d/foo_bar`) fails also. Opening the file using vi, saving it (`:wq`) without making any changes and running the validation again succeeds.

My current working thesis: WTF?!

But it's late and I am tired. If anyone has suggestions please let me know. I will update this question as soon as I have new information and I will clean it up once I zero in on a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your file is likely missing its end-of-file newline. `sudo` expects that, and `visudo` will fail to validate a file missing it. Opening a file in Vi and saving it will add a newline at the end if necessary, fixing the file from `sudo`’s perspective.